# Generating SQL with sprintf(): "Too few arguments"

Tags: php

I keep getting the following error message when trying to UPDATE one of my database tables:

```
idrr = 167

age_notes = 'Enumerate, Louisvilleluminary, Nacho Friend, Bulls and Bears, Bricklayer, Activity Report, Interactif, Soundman).\r\n

\r\nBashford Manor S (gr-III, 6f, defeating Flatter Than Me, Brassy Boy, Grand Slam Andre, Soundman, Westrock Gold, Vito Filitto, Even Wilder).\r\n

\r\nA maiden special weight race at Churchill Downs (5f, by 2 3/4, defeating Thiskyhasnolimit, Red Rally, Dublin, Criminal Offense, Congar, Horst, Prospective Union, Victorystart, Harley\'s Heat).'
```

**Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in /data/19/1/60/63/1875552/user/2038041/htdocs/vinery/Admin/upload_stallion.php on line 305
Query was empty**

Right above the Warning is an echo of the two variables used in the `sprintf()`.

Here is the section from my php file:

```
        $idrr = GetSQLValueString($_POST['id1'], "int");
        $associated_horse = GetSQLValueString($_POST['associated_horse1'], "int");
        $year = GetSQLValueString($_POST['year1'], "text");
        $age = GetSQLValueString($_POST['age1'], "int");
        $starts = GetSQLValueString($_POST['starts1'], "int");
        $first = GetSQLValueString($_POST['first1'], "int");
        $first_sw = GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_sw1'], "int");
        $second = GetSQLValueString($_POST['second1'], "int");
        $second_sp = GetSQLValueString($_POST['second_sp1'], "int");
        $third = GetSQLValueString($_POST['third1'], "int");
        $third_sp = GetSQLValueString($_POST['third_sp1'], "int");
        $age_notes = GetSQLValueString($_POST['age_notes1'], "text");
        $age_text = GetSQLValueString($_POST['age_text1'], "text");
        $earned = GetSQLValueString($_POST['earned1'], "text");
        echo ("idrr = " . $idrr . "<br/>");
        echo ("age_notes = " . $age_notes);




        $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE race_records SET age_notes = $age_notes WHERE rr_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($idrr, "int"));

        mysql_select_db($database_XXXXXX, XXXXXX);
        $Result = mysql_query($insertSQL, $HDAdave) or die(mysql_error())
```

I can't figure out why this particular UPDATE wont work.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to put backticks or single quotes around `$age_notes` and `%s`

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE race_records SET age_notes = '$age_notes' WHERE rr_id = '%s'", GetSQLValueString($idrr, "int"));
```

Comment: Added an echo GetSQLValueString($_POST['id1'], "int");
and put '' around age_notes and %s.

Comment: idrr = 167
age_notes = 'CORRECT STRING truncated for space'
167

Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in /data/19/1/60/63/1875552/user/2038041/htdocs/vinery/Admin/upload_stallion.php on line 305
Query was empty

Comment: Can you replace %s with the value of idrr and remove sprintf completely?

Comment: I'll try that in a second.  Wanted to mention that all the other variables you see also need to be in this UPDATE but I found that the age_notes was causing this problem, so I was isolating it in the code I have shown.

Comment: @cenanozen Yes that work's and the UPDATE is successful.  What was the matter with using the sprintf()?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure but it is probably a type issue, maybe your GetSQLValueString wasn't returning a string ?

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is not to mix sprintf with $var-substituted strings. So you should use either

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE race_records SET age_notes = '%s' WHERE rr_id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($age_notes), mysql_real_escape_string(GetSQLValueString($idrr, "int")) );
```

or

```
$insertSQL = "UPDATE race_records SET age_notes = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($age_notes) . "' WHERE rr_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(GetSQLValueString($idrr, "int")) . "'";
```

You were getting this error message probably because `$age_notes` contains % symbol and that's messing up `sprintf`.

@cenanozen's advice on using quotes is good too (though it doesn't answer your particular question).

Remember to quote all strings in SQL using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or something else!